# What popular online services allow passwordless authentication using digital signatures?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, web-service

I am looking for web services that allow clients to authenticate using digital signatures.

Especially with e-commerce and payments, clients generally authenticate using name and password (sometimes using an additional factor). I'm looking for something entirely different: services where the client is authenticated by digitally signing a challenge provided by the server, otherwise providing no password at all.

I'm especially interested in web services in the field of e-commerce, but I'll take any well known web service that can be used to construct a mashup demo -- so far I wasn't able to find any.

Are any of you familiar with any such services?

Answer (score 1):

PKI isn't a very popular approach to [2 factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-factor_authentication) outside the enterprise because of the overhead of protecting the private keys and managing certificates, but there are some commercial solutions available.

Take a look at [Layer7](http://www.layer7tech.com/solutions/pki-for-web-services).

Years ago I used to work for [Baltimore Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_Technologies) (famous for the first digital signature of legislation ([by Bill Clinton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_Technologies) and Bertie Ahern)) and we looked at doing exactly what you are wanting. Two factor authentication using digital signatures. The problems really are:

- Where are the keys going to be  generated and stored?
- Who can access the keys? and
- How to we interface between the client and the device which holds the keys?

These are not easy questions to answer, but technologies like [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) may eventually come in to answer some of them. However, keys will still not be mobile. So maybe eventually we can use mobile devices for key storage? But, what happens when the device is lost / stolen / broken? And, again, how to we link to device to the client browser for authentication purposes?

Perhaps the most interesting implementation of device authentication I have seen is that by Barclays Bank. PINSentry uses a handheld device and your bank ATM / debit card in order to provide authentication to the Barclays online services. Check [it](http://www.barclays.co.uk/Helpsupport/HowtousePINsentry/P1242560253457) out. This isn't a [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) implementation. Its a one-time password application, but the application is executed on the [smartcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javacard).

The most popular method for two-factor authentication is [one-time password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password). These come in a variety of forms and can be provided by [dedicated devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID) or mobile devices. Look at [Authy](https://www.authy.com/), [VIP Access](https://idprotect.verisign.com/desktop/home.v) or Google [Authenticator](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/).